# How to access the struct attributes inside an STL Stack C++?

Tags: c++, struct, stl

Here is my code

```
struct vidstruct {
   int Video_ID;  // -> Increment 
   string movietitle = "";
   string genre = "";
   string prod = "";
   int numberOfCopies;
   string MovImg_name;
};

struct customerstruct {
   int Customer_ID;
   string name;
   string adress;
   stack <vidstruct> cstack;  // -> I want to access this one

// here is my declaration of methods
public:
   VideoClass();
   void returnVideo(vidstruct info,int sc); // ---
```

Here is what I am doing to try to access it:

```
    void VideoClass::returnVideo(vidstruct info,int sc) {
    int top;
    list<customerstruct>::iterator iter;
    
    for (iter = myListCustomer.begin(); iter != myListCustomer.end(); iter++) { 

        if (sc == iter->Customer_ID) {
            cout << iter->Customer_ID << " " << endl;
            cout << iter->name << " " << endl;
            cout << iter->adress << " " << endl;
            cout << "Videos Rented: " << endl;

            while (!iter->cstack.empty()) {
                iter->cstack.top();
                cout << info.Video_ID << "   " << info.movietitle; // This is what I'm trying to do but it just gives me a random output.

                iter->cstack.pop();

            }
```

I want to access the Video_ID and the movietitle attributes of the vidstruct Structure but I'm really lost on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a complete (but minimum) example that will demo what you're looking for (perhaps). I've tried to keep things as close as possible to your example.

https://wandbox.org/permlink/88WSws0aM8hVpsDh

Please (Please!!): go and learn how `stack` and `list` work (and when you should use one over the other), what's the difference between `struct` and `class`, just to mention very few things I see to improve there.